# Java - Download from OneDrive public folder

Tags: java, download, onedrive, htmlunit, public

I have a link for OneDrive. The format is https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%XXXXX

The link is public, it's not mine and new files is often added in it. My question is simple. What is the best way in Java to list all the file/folder from this link and to download a file ?

I tried HtmlUnit but it give a big javascript error.
Since the link is public, do I really need to use a OneDrive SDK ? I really don't know how to proccess with OneDrive... Thank's for any help

Comment: Please report the error to the HtmlUnit github project.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/isac322/OneDrive-SDK-java This SDK will help you get the path and download the folder.

Comment: Thank you ! And how can I access the folder with this SDK, since it's not my folder ?

Comment: It should be in the explanations when you scroll down, the readme.md file

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content?view=odsp-graph-online also will be helpful if you would like to use the official api